# boost msm euml fusion issue

Tags: c++, boost

I am actually working in boost::msm with eUML, which is really a great thing and I created some simpler FSM with it before.

However I am facing an issue, that I am not able to solve, so I hope to get some help here.

The code is fairly easy (but a bit long - see end of this post). The issue is located within the transition table, that is somewho misformed:

```
BOOST_MSM_EUML_TRANSITION_TABLE ((

  state_entryPrimary == state_init  [ fsm_(FsmNo) == Int_<fsm_primary>() ]   ,
  state_entrySecondary == state_init  [ fsm_(FsmNo) == Int_<fsm_secondary>() ] ,

  state_1 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_1>() ],
  state_2 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_3>() ], //!!!!!
  state_3 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_4>() ],
  state_6 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_2>() ],

  state_4 == state_1 + event_1,
  state_5 == state_4 + event_2,
  state_1 == state_3 + event_3,
  state_7 == state_6 + event_4,
  state_exit == state_5 + event_9,
  state_exit == state_7 + event_9

), my_transition_table)
```

I got a **very** long error message with g++ 5.4.0 and boost 1.58 based on some fusion code that failed to build the code. The first error line is like:

```
/usr/include/boost/fusion/container/set/convert.hpp:27:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct boost::fusion::detail::barrier::as_set<11>’
```

In case, I comment out the line marked with //!!!!!, the FSM compiles without any issue.

Is somebody out there, who could help with this?

```
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/euml.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/state_grammar.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/back/state_machine.hpp>
#include <boost/msm/front/euml/operator.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace msm = boost::msm;
using namespace boost::msm::front::euml;
using namespace msm::front::euml;

enum UStatusType {
    statid_1,
    statid_2,
    statid_3,
    statid_4
};

enum FsmType {
    fsm_primary,
    fsm_secondary
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_ATTRIBUTE(UStatusType, uStatus)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_ATTRIBUTE(FsmType, FsmNo)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_ATTRIBUTE(int, cnt)

BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(act_do_a) { 
  template <class Evt,class Fsm, class State> void operator()(Evt const& ,Fsm& fsm, State& state ) const
    { std::cout << " -> do a " << std::endl; } 
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_ACTION(act_do_b) {
  template <class Evt,class Fsm, class State> void operator()(Evt const& ,Fsm& fsm, State& state ) const
    { std::cout << " -> do b " << std::endl; }
};

BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((), state_init)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_b), state_exit)

BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((), state_entryPrimary)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_1)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_2)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_3)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_4)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_5)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_6)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((act_do_a), state_7)

BOOST_MSM_EUML_STATE((), state_entrySecondary)

BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT(event_1)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT(event_2)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT(event_3)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT(event_4)
BOOST_MSM_EUML_EVENT(event_9)


BOOST_MSM_EUML_TRANSITION_TABLE ((

  state_entryPrimary == state_init  [ fsm_(FsmNo) == Int_<fsm_primary>() ]   ,
  state_entrySecondary == state_init  [ fsm_(FsmNo) == Int_<fsm_secondary>() ] ,

  state_1 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_1>() ],
  state_2 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_3>() ], //!!!!!
  state_3 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_4>() ],
  state_6 == state_entryPrimary [ fsm_(uStatus) == Int_<statid_2>() ],

  state_4 == state_1 + event_1,
  state_5 == state_4 + event_2,
  state_1 == state_3 + event_3,
  state_7 == state_6 + event_4,
  state_exit == state_5 + event_9,
  state_exit == state_7 + event_9

), my_transition_table)

BOOST_MSM_EUML_DECLARE_STATE_MACHINE((my_transition_table, init_ << state_init, no_action, no_action, 
    attributes_ << FsmNo << uStatus << cnt ), my_fsm)

int main()
{
  msm::back::state_machine<my_fsm> my;

  // testing some start conditions
  my.get_attribute(uStatus) = statid_1; // read from device
  my.get_attribute(FsmNo) = fsm_primary;
  my.get_attribute(cnt) = 1;

  my.start(); 
  my.process_event(event_1);
  my.process_event(event_2);
  my.process_event(event_9);

  std::cout << "\nRestart Statemachine with statid_3\n\n";
  my.get_attribute(uStatus) = statid_3;
  my.start();
  my.process_event(event_3);

  std::cout << "\nRestart Statemachine with statid_2\n\n";
  my.get_attribute(uStatus) = statid_2;
  my.start();
  my.process_event(event_4);
  my.process_event(event_9);
}
```

Comment: When updating to boost 1.63, the issue dissapears, so issue is solved by that.

Answer (score 0):

Define `FUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE` to whatever you need before the include section. In case your transition table exceeds 20 entries, following defines have to be added:

```
#define BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_VECTOR_SIZE 30 //max table size                   
#define BOOST_MPL_LIMIT_MAP_SIZE 30 //max table size
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/msm/doc/HTML/ch03s02.html#d0e358